# Is hp compaq elite 8300 supported for Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit version?

Tags: hardware

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit on a HP Compaq Elite 8300 PC. Sometimes my machine freezes while I'm working. I want to know whether Ubuntu is well-supported on this hardware.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Version. 12.04 or 12.04.1 or 12.04.2 or 12.04.3. If you recently updated your Ubuntu, then it might be 12.04.3. Reply..